# Implement CultureInfo for decimal to comma in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to convert decimal value to **comma(,)** in my Report Wizard. So
I tried to Implement this following `CultureInfo("fr-FR")` code in the Code Behind page.

```
transactionMaster = transactionSettings.GetTransactionMasterForFleetSalesReport
                           (
                            strCardNumber,
                            TypeDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                            Convert.ToDateTime(SearchFromdateTextBox.Text),
                            Convert.ToDateTime(SearchToDateTextBox.Text)
                           );

foreach (var data in transactionMaster)
{
    string withcomma = "";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    withcomma = data.Total.ToString();
    withcomma.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    data.Total = withcomma;
}   

ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("FleetSalesAll", (object)transactionMaster);
TransactionCount = transactionMaster.Count;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

string name = datasource.Name;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\IndividualFleetSaleReport.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
ReportParameter[] rp = new ReportParameter[5];
rp[0] = new ReportParameter("FromDate", this.SearchFromdateTextBox.Text);
rp[1] = new ReportParameter("ToDate", this.SearchToDateTextBox.Text);
rp[2] = new ReportParameter("ReportHeader", "Individual Card Transactions");
rp[3] = new ReportParameter("ReportExecutionTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
rp[4] = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", "file:////" + Server.MapPath("~/Images/company-logo.png"));
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp);
```

Actually I had declare this total in decimal datatype. So here I'm
getting:

> Cannot Convert decimal to string** error.

If I convert this into decimal then I cannot get the actually result.
Is there any Idea to Convert **decimal(.)** to **comma(,)** using Culture
Info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to do that. The datatype should always keep the 'proper' version (period as comma) and then when you display the data on a UI, then you can use Culture to show it with a decimal point as comma separator. But you shouldn't store it with comma. It'll make it all the more difficult to run calculations on the value.

Comment: [XY](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) [problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) ?

Comment: The `,` or `.` part is only in the presentation. The decimal value itself doesn't care at all about that, and it's a good thing. You should only specify the output format when you're presenting the results - at the point where you're actually doing the `ToString` and showing the data to the user (or rendering it to the page, as it may be). `data.Total` is the number itself - you can't assign a `string` to it, yet it's only in the string representation that the decimal separator appears (be it `,`, `.` or `|` or whatever you want).

Comment: I don't see why users would vote down a legitimate question, just because the the OP initially got it wrong?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: In French Machine Report are generated in Comma(,) instead of decimal(.)  so I have to Implement this format in my machine too. If I can convert this decimal(.) to Comma(,) then I will easily convert in French machine too.

Comment: what type is data.Total? is it a string? Is there a reason why try to use Culture and not just string.Replace? `data.Total = withcomma;` shows that it might be string...

Comment: @Uriel_SVK No that `Total` is declared in decimal.. I could not change that because That Total was used in many places in my application

Comment: @dinesh.k is the problem only that the data are represented on your and french computer differently? how are you supplying the data? Are you using binding? can you post you asp code?

Answer (score 1):

Really no idea where are you heading here - if `data.Total` is decimal it does not matter if it is on french or englich machine. If you want to force some culture for printing the data, you can use 
`data.Total.ToString(culture)`

MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("eu-ES");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(culture));
// Displays:    16325,62
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays:    16325.62
```

so it should be

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
string withcoma = data.Total.ToString(culture);
```

Edit:

Try to add

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
```

somewhere in pageload, also remove that `foreach` there is no way that gonna work.

Comment: In about example it just print the decimal values but in my Scenario I need to store that CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-ES") to data.Total..

Comment: if the data.Total is decimal culture has no effect, but i think im starting to understand what you are asking - added comment to question. If the problem is only in presentation of data pls post your asp code

Comment: Edited answer, try it pls

Answer (score 1):

Even though your input is using comma as decimal point, you shall not/cannot store it with comma in a decimal datatype. 
That would require a string and that's absolutely not adviceable.

Instead - take your input and store it as Decimal as is correct; basically:

```
data.Total = Decimal.Parse("your input", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));
```

Then you have a clean and workable decimal datatype in data.Total (as you seem to have already), which you can display anywhere as what you want and safely perform calculations on.

When you need to show your decimal value to a user, you format your decimal datatype to the specific culture.

```
string withcomma = data.Total.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));
```

this way you don't end up with strange data type conversion errors or wrong calculations and you still get to display it as comma decimal point.

Using wrong data types is a major causes of errors in computer systems, so it's always the best approach to keep the correct data type and just convert it for output.
That's what globalization is used for in .NET.

Comment: I need to assign this converted value to table                                          
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");                                string withcoma = data.Total.ToString(culture);
data.Total = withcoma;                                                                             but this **Total** was declared in decimal and **withcoma** was declare in string.

Comment: If you need to display the data, just do the formatting you're already doing, but you should not store it back into a data.Total which is the decimal, and should be kept format-free.